# Most useful Visual Studio capabilities and tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I feel like I've been neglecting this powerful tool and not using it to full capacity. What are the most useful Visual Studio capabilities or tools that you use most often?

Comment: Should be Community Wiki

Comment: @Simple Coder: will become automatically CW when there are enough answers here.

Comment: No more CW, poll questions are off topic for SO.  They don't fit the Q+A pattern.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D

Reformat your Code 
And you can also press `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C` to comment a block of code, `Ctrl+K, Ctrl+U` to uncomment a block of code.
There is somthing I really like in VS where you can press `F12` to go to the defenition of a variable or class...etc

Answer (score 6):

Auto-completion of certain structures like for/while/switch/try etc when you hit your tab key twice after typing the first keyword, e.g: type "for" and then hit tab twice. Love it! :)

Answer (score 5):

Pressing **Ctrl + .** will bring up a list of availible namespaces for an object when you finish typing out the Type.

It saves a of a lot of time when you don't remember the namespace that a your newely entered type belongs to.  It's also useful for those lazy moments where you don't want to leave the line of code you're on to type out a using statement at the top of your class.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's not part of VS, but Resharper is awesome.

Comment: Also not part of VS, but I have come to love the VisualSVN plug-in.

Answer (score 4):

Finding all references to a function or a variable within my solution.

Answer (score 3):

Mixed language debugging.

Answer (score 3):

All of the internal refactoring capabilities. The most useful, for me, is Encapsulate Field. I hate manually writing simple property getters and setters. Another great one is the rename feature, although this isn't unique to only VS.

Also, VS has the best Intellisense, in my opinion, especially when compared to Eclipse and Netbeans. They have pretty good Intellisense, but not as accurate or as helpful as VS.

And finally, the Object Browser. The Object Browser is a great way to search for a method or property that you *know* exists, but can't find. It's also good for exploring undocumented (or poorly advertised) functionality.

Comment: "VS has the best Intellisense" what language?

Comment: In general; it works better than Intellisense-type mechanisms in other products. I've used it for C# and VB.Net extensively, and it's great.

Answer (score 3):

Attaching the debugger to an already running process.

Answer (score 1):

```
Alt + Shift + Down Arrow
```

Select multiple lines of code and edit them all at once - I don't use it that often, but when I do it comes in handy!

Answer (score 1):

```
ctrl + ,
```

is probably my favorite. Navigate To: type in your search and walla, open quickly.

This only works for VS 2010

Answer (score 0):

The WinForms designer is very handy and powerful. What I like most is that GUI descriptions are not buried in some "binary graveyard". They are expressed in human-readable code which can be globally searched/replaced, diffed etc.

Answer (score 0):

Debugger step through - very handy feature.

Answer (score 0):

Attach to Process and Remote Debugging

Answer (score 0):

I think the below link is very handy

http://www.dofactory.com/reference/visual-studio-shortcuts

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, since if the link changes the info is lost.  Its best to post the essentials, even though this is essentially what the poster is asking for...